# Im using alamofire to parse json to sign up, im using mysql database

Tags: node.js, swift, alamofire

that's my API code using nodejs, I get on Xcode console that the user is registered successfully but he's not added on the database, is it the problem on my API or in my swift source code? any help, please? I don't think that the problem is in my API cause I'm testing it on postman and it works well

```
app.post('/register/',(req,res,next)=>{
    var post_data = req.body;  //Get POST params
    var uid = uuid.v4();   //Get  UUID V4
    var plaint_password = post_data.password ;  //Get password from post params
    var hash_data = saltHashPassword(plaint_password);
    var password = hash_data.passwordHash;  //Get Hash value
    var salt = hash_data.salt; //Get salt

    var name = post_data.name;
    var email = post_data.email;
    var prenom = post_data.prenom
    var tel_user = post_data.tel_user;

    con.query('SELECT * FROM user where email=?',[email],function (err,result,fields) {
        con.on('error',function (err) {
            console.log('[MYSQL ERROR]',err);

        });
        if (result && result.length)
            res.json('Cette adresse mail est déjà utilisé');
        else {
            con.query('INSERT INTO `user`(`unique_id`, `name`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `salt`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `prenom`, `tel_user`) ' +
                'VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW(),?,?)',[uid,name,email,password,salt,prenom,tel_user],function (err,result,fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

                res.json('Vous ètes inscrit avec succés');

            })
        }
    });

})
```

and that's how im using alamofire to parse json data

```
@IBAction func btn_register(_ sender: Any) {
        let serverUrl = "http://localhost:1337/register"

        guard let email = emailtf.text, !email.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let password = passwordtf.text, !password.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let name = nametf.text, !name.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let prenom = prenomtf.text, !prenom.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let telephone = telephonetf.text, !telephone.isEmpty else {return}

        let registerRequest = [
            "name" : name,
            "email" : email,
            "password" : password,
             "prenom" : prenom,
            "telephone" : telephone,
        ]

        print(registerRequest)




              Alamofire.request(serverUrl, method: .post, parameters: registerRequest, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
                    if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                        let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                        print(resJson)



                    }
                    if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                        let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                        print(error)
                    }


           }


    }
```

I get on XCode console that the user is registered successfully but it's not added on the database, is it the problem on my API, or in my swift source code? I don't think that the problem is in my API, because I'm testing it on postman and it works fine.

Comment: do you set ATS key in info.plist?

Comment: yes sure, already done